# Derive a formula of a specific curve

Tags: regression

I have this curve [image]

And I know that the first point is

$$A(0,5)$$

and the last point is

$$C(1650,9.5)$$

The point almost at the center where the curve changes (if you look close, you can see a green dot) is

$$B(1000,8.5)$$

There is a way to derive a generic f(x) so that I can plug in a value of x and find f(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know four properties: $f(0)=5$, $f(1000)=8.5$, $f(1650)=9.5$ and $f'(1000)=0$. To fit a polynomial with these constraints we need a degree of at least three:

$$f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
$$f'(x) = 3ax^2+2bx+c$$

Plugging in what we know gives the following equation system.

$$\begin{cases} 
a+b+c+d=5 \\ 10^9a+10^6b+10^3c+d=8.5 \\ 1650^3a+1650^2b+1650c+d=9.5 \\ 3000000a+2000b+c=0 \\
\end{cases}$$
Solving this and plotting the resulting $f(x)$, gives the following curve. Does this look good enough?

[image]

The solution:

$$\begin{cases}
a=3.562082728528 \cdot 10^{-9} \\
b=-1.063473805380 \cdot 10^{-5} \\
c=0.010583227922\\
d=4.989427403254\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Great! Do you have any resources on how to come up whit a solution like this? I want to learn instead of spamming question on math.stackexchange :D

Comment: @Kahel [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting#Fitting_lines_and_polynomial_curves_to_data_points) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) is some information. Good luck!